# How to integrate openiconic with plantuml.jar?

Tags: plantuml, creole

I am using the current version of plantuml.jar (1.2023.13). I create my drawings using the Visual Studio Code plugin on Mac.

For the first time, I am trying to use Open Iconic in my diagram. My understanding is that it is already integrated in Plantuml. However, I get a syntax error on "listopeniconic" command:

```
@startuml
listopeniconic
@enduml
```

Is there some additional plugin I need to download? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you showed the error message you are getting. I'm using Windows VSCode with 1.2023.6 of PlantUML and it's working. What does the `version` command (similar to `listopeniconic`) show when you run that? It will give other diagnostic info, including graphviz and some JVM info.